# Metapost : how to insert accented letter inside label

Tags: metapost

I need to insert accented letter é, è, à.  within labels in a matapost code. how can I do that

Note: I compile my document with `pdflatex --shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mpgraphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{mpdisplay}
 pair A;
    A := (0,0);
    draw A withpen pencircle scaled 4bp;
    label.lft(btex  café  etex, A);
    label.rt (btex algèbre  etex, A);
\end{mpdisplay}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to your code? (or any font which exists in T1 encoding).

Comment: It seems as if you'd have to insert them separately, e.g. `é` has to be inserted as `\'{e}`.

Comment: I have a similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366081/how-to-support-unicode-characters-in-metapost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell Metapost that you're using UTF-8 and T1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mpgraphics}

\begin{ltxpreamble}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\end{ltxpreamble}

\begin{document}

\begin{mpdisplay}
 pair A;
    A := (0,0);
    draw A withpen pencircle scaled 4bp;
    label.lft(btex \strut café  etex, A);
    label.rt (btex \strut algèbre  etex, A);
\end{mpdisplay}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `gmp` it would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\usempxpackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usempxpackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{mpost}
 pair A;
    A := (0,0);
    draw A withpen pencircle scaled 4bp;
    label.lft(\btex \strut café  etex, A);
    label.rt (\btex \strut algèbre  etex, A);
\end{mpost}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using LuaTeX.  There you have UTF-8 support out-of-the-box when you use a correctly mapped font (by loading `fontspec`).  Also, LuaTeX has a builtin Metapost processor which removes the necessity for shell escape.  You have to load `luamplib` for that.  Perhaps there are also other, higher-level packages for this which I am not aware of.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luamplib}
% for convenience
\everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
  pair A;
  A := (0,0);
  draw A withpen pencircle scaled 4bp;
  label.lft(btex  café  etex, A);
  label.rt (btex algèbre  etex, A);
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or just use ConTeXt (same output).  Thanks to Metafun you don't even need the annoying `btex .. etex`, but can just use quotes.

```
\starttext
\startMPcode
  pair A;
  A := (0,0);
  draw A withpen pencircle scaled 4bp;
  label.lft("café", A);
  label.rt ("algèbre", A);
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks @HenriMenke, but I need to compile my file with `pdflatex`

Comment: Note that you'll want the struts as egreg used to get the two words on the same baseline (at least in luatex).