# How to support unicode characters in metapost?

Tags: unicode, metapost

I have a metapost file which I compile via mpost .
This file contains special characters which cannot be displayed
when I include the file in latex.
I have required inputenc utf8 in latex.

Does anybody know an answer for this?

Comment: perhaps this is helpful: [Metapost : how to insert accented letter inside label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321853/579)

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your workflow?  Are you creating an `.eps` file out of Metapost?  Can you post a minimal example of a MP file that shows the problem, and the latex file you use to include it?  One simple way to use unicode in MP  is to use `luamplib` and `lualatex`, could this work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't say much about your environment so I'm guessing.

Here are three ways to set unicode characters in Metapost.

### Traditional Latex

To use UTF8 in your label strings, you can do this sort of thing:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
verbatimtex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
etex
beginfig(1);
label.top(btex sprichwörtlichen etex, origin);
draw (left--right) scaled 2cm;
endfig;
end.
```

To get Metapost to use `latex` to process this, you need to compile it with:

`mpost -tex=latex  <filename>`

On my system this produces:

[image]

Using this set up you should be able to use any Unicode characters that the `utf8` encoding knows about.  You may find it more convenient to convert the `.eps` file produced into a `.pdf` file before you include it into your `.tex` file.

### Modern LuaLaTeX

My personal preference today is to use `lualatex` for all Metapost work with the `luamplib` library.  The advantage is that you get the whole `fontspec` environment working for you and you can use any of the proper OTF fonts you have installed.  Here I have used `Linux Libertine O` as the font, which has a good range of Unicode characters defined.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    label.top("☞ sprichwörtlichen", origin);
    draw (left--right) scaled 2cm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You compile this with `lualatex <filename>` which produces:

[image]

If you are not ready to adopt `lualatex` as your main LaTeX engine, then you can do what I have done here and use the `standalone` class to generate a, er, standalone PDF file for your MP graphic.

### Old fashioned plain Metapost

(Really don't do this...)

If you would like to stick with old fashioned plain Metapost, and not use LaTeX at all, it is still possible to support at least a subset of UTF8 with the built in `infont` operator.

Consider this following MP program:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def U primary s = if string s: decode(s) fi enddef;

vardef decode(expr given) = 
    save a, i, s, out; string s, out; numeric a, i;
    out = ""; i=0;
    forever:
        s := substring (i, incr i) of given; 
        a := ASCII s;
        if a < 128: 
        elseif a = 194: 
            s := substring (i, incr i) of given;
        elseif a = 195: 
            s := char (64 + ASCII substring (i, incr i) of given);
        else: 
            s := "?";
        fi
        out := out & s;
        exitif i >= length given;
    endfor
    out
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    defaultfont := "phvr8r";
    label.top(U"sprichwörtlichen", origin);
    draw (left--right) scaled 2cm;
endfig;
end.
```

This can be compiled with plain old `mpost` with no options and it produces:

[image]

but beware that the simple, quick-and-dirty `decode` routine only supports a very limited subset of UTF8, and it is converting what it does to ISO8859-1, or rather to the close approximation to ISO8859-1 that is provided by the `8r` encoding used with the `phvr8r` font.  On the other hand it is quick...

### Notes

- The main loop of `decode` shows a "slick" way to step through a string.
  The `incr` macro is from plain MP: it increases the value of a numeric variable by 1 and then returns that value.  This exactly what we need to use `substring` to read each character in the string.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the last solution since I just needed Umlaute :D