# Text label in MetaPost: language support

Tags: labels, languages, input-encodings, font-encodings, metapost

I am working with the example:

```
beginfig(1);
label.urt("Текст на русском.", origin);
label.llft("Text in English.", origin);
endfig;
```

The output contains:

```
Missing character: There is no 208 in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no 162 in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no 208 in font cmr10!
...
```

What I've tried:

- different values of the `prologues` variable (1,2 and 3)
- in the beginning of the `.mp` file I wrote:

```
verbatimtex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\nofiles
etex;
```

- also I added to the `mpost` command an option `-tex=latex` (hoping MetaPost would take the language settings in LaTeX...)

As I understand, the `cmr10` font contains Russian symbols. So what do I have to tell MetaPost that it would 'understand' these letters? I've looked through the MetaPost Manual and browsed over the Internet about the problem -- nothing found...

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366277/15036)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *possible* to get this to work with good old `mpost`, but it is 2021 now and frankly it is much easier to use `lualatex` instead.  If I wrap the OP example up in `luamplib`, and choose an appropriate font with good Unicode support, like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
label.urt("Текст на русском.", origin);
label.llft("Text in English.", origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

then compiling with `lualatex` produces this:

[image]

which is probably what you want.  Notice that the font selection is done at the LaTeX level and that Unicode UTF8 is the default encoding.

I do *all* of my MP work like this now, simply for the better integration with LaTeX.  And if you can't use `lualatex` for the rest of your document, then you can at least produce separate PDF files using the `standalone` class, as my example shows.

For documentation, try `texdoc luamplib` on your local system.  Or have a look at sections 11 and 12 of my [Drawing with Metapost](https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost/blob/master/Drawing-with-Metapost.pdf) document (in preparation...).  And [this earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366277/15036).

### Plain old Metapost version

If you are (for whatever reason) really stuck with plain `mpost`, then you might be able to get away with something like this.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def CY primary s = if string s: decode_some_cyrillic(s) infont "fcmr6z" fi enddef;

vardef decode_some_cyrillic(expr given) = 
    save a, b, i, s, out; string s, out; numeric a, b, i;
    out = ""; i=0;
    forever:
        s := substring (i, incr i) of given; 
        a := ASCII s;
        if a < 128: 
        elseif a = 208: 
            s := substring (i, incr i) of given;
            b := ASCII s;
            s := if (143 < b) and (b < 192): char (b + 48) else: "?" fi;
        elseif a = 209: 
            s := substring (i, incr i) of given;
            b := ASCII s;
            s := if (127 < b) and (b < 144): char (b + 112) else: "?" fi;
        else: 
            s := "?";
        fi
        out := out & s;
        exitif i >= length given;
    endfor
    out
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    label.top(CY"Текст на русском.", origin);
    draw (left--right) scaled 2cm;
endfig;
end
```

Provided that your system has a Cyrillic font called `fcmr6z` then
compiling this with plain `mpost` should produce:

[image]

And just for reference, here is the font layout:

[image]

But the `luamplib` solution is a much better way to go!

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to get this to work like good old mpost: using [minim-mp](https://ctan.org/pkg/minim-mp), which includes a format file that allows you to use luatex as if it were a stand-alone metapost-to-pdf processor.

Minim-mp is based on plain TeX, so you have to specify the font in your metapost file like this:

```
verbatimtex
\font \cmu = {CMU Serif Roman} at 10pt
etex;

beginfig(1);
defaultfont := "cmu";
label.urt("Текст на русском.", origin);
label.llft("Text in English.", origin);
endfig;

bye
```

You can then compile it with `luatex -fmt minim-mp <filename>.mp`. (If the format file is not found, you should create it first with `luatex -ini minim-mp.ini`.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!