# How to define a function in metapost that draw graph based on a string?

Tags: metapost

In algebraic topology, we need to draw polygon with label that indicate the identification of edges. For example, [image]
shows the glue of $a_1$ and $a_1$ along the arrow.

My question is how to define a function in metapost that

- draw the polygon with arrows and labels
- based on a input like ATdraw(a1+,a2+,a3+,a4+,a5+,a1-,a2-,a3-,a4-,a5-)

Note that the + and - indicated the direction is counterclockwise or clockwise oriented, respectively, and we start from the bottom edge and label the edge counterclockwise.

Thanks in advance!

I have a try in metapost, by it seems I don't know how to split the input string into a list, which then can be operated on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef ATdraw(text t) = 
    save n, edge; 
    numeric n; n = 0;
    string edge[];
    for s=t:
        edge[incr n] = s;
    endfor
    save poly; path poly; 
    poly = for i=0 upto n-1: 80 down rotated (360/n*i-180/n) -- endfor cycle;
    ahangle := 30;
    image(
        for i=1 upto n:
            string sense, marker; 
            sense = substring (0, 1) of edge[i];
            marker = substring (1, length edge[i]) of edge[i];
            if sense = "+":
                drawarrow subpath (i-1, i-1/2) of poly;
                draw      subpath (i-1/2, i) of poly;
            else:
                drawarrow subpath (i, i-1/2) of poly;
                draw      subpath (i-1/2, i-1) of poly;
            fi
            label("$" & marker & "$", 84 down rotated (360/n*(i-1)));
        endfor
    )
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    draw ATdraw("+a_1","+a_2","+a_3","+a_4","+a_5","-a_1","-a_2","-a_3","-a_4","-a_5");
    draw ATdraw("+b_{10}","+b_{20}","+b_{30}","-b_{40}","+b_{50}") shifted 200 right;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a picture like this:

[image]

### Notes

- It is easier if your arguments are strings.  Then you can have arbitrary contents.  Otherwise each argument has to be a valid bit of MP syntax.  In this case `a5-` for example is not valid.
- I've defined my strings to have a leading `+` or `-`, followed by a bit of math-mode TeX for the edge label.
- To process a variable number of arguments you can use the `text` parameter specifier.  Here is it used to read everything into a variable called `t`.  Then you can step through `t` using the simple loop shown.  MP will automatically split `t` at each comma.

Comment: Can `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` also be used with standalone metapost and if so, how?

Comment: No, it is a feature of `luamplib`.   It is harder to process dynamically constructed strings with TeX in plain MP.  But not impossible.  You need to import the TEX.mp macros and then use something like `TEX("$" & variable & "$")`.

Comment: @Thruston Many thanks, which works perfectly for me.  I am wondering could it be possible to further simplify the input as `ATdraw("+b_{10}+b_{20}")` and so on? which will require the split the string by `+` or `-`.

Comment: Yes of course.  But then you miss the elegant simplicity of reading all the arguments at once and looping through them automatically.  You would have to use `substring` to read through the string and split it accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at the way it is done in the third part of this answer.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366277/15036